# Powershell - Combining Looped Results

Tags: powershell

I previously posted this script and had some help but later deleted it to avoid confusion.  I have it almost working with the one exception.  The content of the email sent to each manager only includes the data from the last direct report in the array.  Do I need to restructure the script?  I feel like I am chasing my tail if I had one :)

EDIT: I added the recommended changes, but now I get:

- Email 1: Manager and direct reports
- Email 2: Content of Email 1 and the next Manager and direct reports.
- Email 3: Content of Email 1 & 2, the next Manager and direct reports.....

RESOLVED: Thanks TheMadTechnician.  Modifying the += and moving the $body to the proper location in the loops was the key.

My script Updated script:

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

$today = (Get-Date).ToString()

# Html
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:Lavender ;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:PaleGoldenrod}"
$a = $a + "</style>"


# Email Variables
$smtp = "192.168.1.1"
$to = "User@Company.com"
$from = "User@company.com"
$subject = "Managers - Direct Report's Group Membership"

$managers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties name, directreports, EmailAddress | where {$_.directreports -ne $Null}

foreach ($i in $managers) 
{
    $mgrname = $i.Name
    $mgremail = $i.EmailAddress
    $dreports = $i.directreports
    $body = "Report Date $today ."
    $body = "`n"
    $body = "<H3>The direct reports for $mgrname<H3>"
    foreach ($d in $dreports)
    {
        $user = get-aduser $d -properties *
        $mems = $user.memberof -replace '^CN=(.+?),(?:OU|CN)=.+','$1' | %{New-Object PSObject -Property @{'Group Membership'=$_}} | convertTo-html -Head $a -Body "<H2>Group Membership.</H2>"
        $dreport = $d -replace '^CN=(.+?),(?:OU|CN)=.+','$1'

        $body += "`n"
        $body += "<H3>Direct Report: $dreport</H3>"
        $body += "`n"
        $body += $mems
        $body += "`n"

     }
      Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml  
}
```

Comment: Didn't I already answer this?

Comment: Partially - I did the following: I changed $body += "Report Data $today" and also moved the 2 following lines above the foreach ($d in $dreports) loop.  The problem is, when I run the script, the email culminate the data.  The first email is fine, but the second email includes the data of the first email with the next manager's direct reports and the 3rd includes the 1st and 2nd plus the 3rd managers direct reports.

Comment: Change it back to $body= as long as it is outside that loop it should work fine then

Comment: TheMadTechnician - Bingo! Thanks! Can you comment in the main thread so I can give you credit since you helped me first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, resolution for this issue was to move the bulk of the email generation outside of the ForEach($d in $dreports) loop. The header section ($Body='Report for $today', and the following two lines) was moved up, and the line to actually send the mail was moved down outside of the loop. Updated code is already in the OP I think, so I won't bother to repost it again.

Comment: Thanks TheMadTechnician for your help orginally.  Also thanks to everyone else's input as well.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

> $body = "Report Date $today ."

Is resetting the $body variable for each direct report. So by the time you get to Send-MailMessage all you have is the last direct report.

Try moving that line above the foreach loop that iterates through the direct reports.

Comment: A bit disappointed by him deleting his last question and only half way updating his script with my answer. Yes, this is exactly what the issue is. The `$Body = "Report Date: $today"` line needs to be move above the `ForEach($d in $dreports)` line. Actually, the 2 lines after `$Body = ` need to be moved up as well. This answer should resolve the issue, already +1'd it.

Comment: TheMadTechnician - Sorry I had to delete the previous post.  I was trying to contact you via a message to apologize.  I tried your recommendation which was included in this script.  I will take yours and the others recommendations.  Again sorry for any possible offense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to send all reports as individual emails to all managers, move the `Send-MailMessage` call inside the report `foreach` loop.

Or if you want to send one email containing all reports to each manager, declare `$body` outside of you report loop and change the first assigment within the loop to `$body += "Report Date $today ."

Answer (score 0):

Every iteration of `foreach ($d in $dreports)` resets `$body`. Change the line

```
$body = "Report Date $today ."
```

to

```
$body += "Report Date $today ."
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input! I've been in meetings all day so I won't get to this until the morning :(